# Redirect page in Angular through the POST method?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

How can I integrate an Angular application with a `WebCheckOut`, because I need to make a POST request to that `WebCheckOut` with the purchase data. The problem is that the concept of Angular applications are single page app, and what I need is to redirect the flow of my application to that payment gateway (`WebCheckOut`).

In summary, my question is: How can I make a POST request in Angular with parameters that redirects me to the domain of the payment gateway (`WebCheckOut`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a regular HTML form somewhere, configured to post to WebCheckOut and then you need to submit it. All of this using regular HTML/JavaScript - Angular will only get in the way for this.

Here is some jquery code which does something similar (which you can call from within Angular).

```
function postForm() {
    $('body').append('<form action="http://www.climatecare.org/home.aspx" method="post" id="hidden_calc">'
        +'<input type="hidden" name="clientCode" value="climatecare" />'
        +'<input type="hidden" name="fromInput" value="'+$('#fromInput').val()+'" />'
        +'<input type="hidden" name="toInput" value="'+$('#toInput').val()+'" />'
        +'<input type="hidden" type="text" name="passengersNumber" value="'+$('#passengersNumber').val()+'" />'
        +'<input type="hidden" name="Mode" value="'+($('#ret').attr('checked')==true?'return':'oneway')+'" />'
        +'<input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate my emissions" />'
        +'</form>');

    $('#hidden_calc').submit();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what you say, but the problem is that I have already developed my application in angular, and I only need to integrate with the payment gateway ... this is the only option I have ... how can I stop using angular for this? within my angular application

Comment: See the example I have just added, in jquery. You could convert that to angular methods if you wish.